# InfluxDB cannot collect data from remote collectd

Tags: influxdb

I have setup collectd in 3 Linux VMs and Influxdb in 1 VM where collectd is also running, but influxDB cannot fetch data from the remote Linux VMs.

The collectd.conf is having same configuration as it should be only the Server name should differ due to the different IP address and collectd is running successfully in these 3 VMs but somehow the data from these collectd does not reach the influxDB even it is listening on the same port.

The collectd.conf for the network plugin on these 3 VMs is the only difference and the Hostname parameter.

```
<Plugin network>
        Server "IP1" "25826"
</Plugin>

<Plugin network>
        Server "IP2" "25826"
</Plugin>

<Plugin network>
        Server "IP3" "25826"
</Plugin>

Now the influxDB configuration file for collectd is:-
[[collectd]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":25826"
  database = "[COLLECTD DB]"
  retention-policy = ""
```

Now as 1 of the collectd is running in same VM where InfluxDB is running, hence this collectd data is populated in the InfluxDB but the rest collectd data is not populated in the DB. Hence please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you share  all collectd configuration from influxdb config file? `tls-enabled`   and `log-point-errors`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have been asked by my team about the change in requirement. now in each VM, we will have both collectd and influxdb running, so now they work fine.